# Android Application Proguard Rules

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation, minify, android-proguard

While buliding a signed apk(with minifiyEnabled true) without any changes to the  proguard file, I get the following warnings :

```
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:com.github.omadahealth.typefaceview.TypefaceEditText: can't find referenced class android.databinding.BindingAdapter
Warning:com.github.omadahealth.typefaceview.TypefaceTextView: can't find referenced class android.databinding.BindingAdapter
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
Warning:com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
Warning:com.yarolegovich.lovelydialog.LovelyCustomDialog: can't find referenced field 'int ld_custom_view_container' in program class com.yarolegovich.lovelydialog.R$id
Warning:javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DropTargetContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.peer.DragSourceContextPeer
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProvider: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DirectColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.color.ColorSpace
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferByte
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.Raster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferUShort
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.ColorModel
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSnapshot: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Image
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.DataBufferInt
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext 
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find  referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceContext
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.Point
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DragSourceEventProxy: can't find referenced class java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDragEvent
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.FlavorsComparator: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
Warning:org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
Warning:there were 250 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

I understand that this is because proguard is obfuscating some classes that shouldn't be obfuscated.

However if I add any code in the proguard file to fix this problems eg :

```
-keep class javax.security.sasl {*;}
```

the gradle build starts and is stuck at transformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelease stage for several hours without any warnings.

I request you guys to help me with proguard rules to ensure that I am able to generate the signed apk

(Directory Structure:

-app

-lib

lib is a library folder which need not be obfuscated)